# Transpose multiple columns to rows in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I am new to SAS and I want to transpose the following table in SAS

From

```
ID  Var1    Var2    Jul-09  Aug-09  Sep-09      
1   10        15       200     300     
2    5        17      -150     200
```

to

```
ID  Var1    Var2    Date    Transpose  
1   10        15    Jul-09        200  
1   10        15    Aug-09        300  
2    5        17    Aug-09       -150  
2    5        17    Sep-09        200
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you considered `proc transpose`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `proc transpose` to tranform data.

```
options validvarname=any;

data a;
    infile datalines missover;
    input ID Var1 Var2 "Jul-09"n "Aug-09"n "Sep-09"n;
datalines;
1 10 15 200 300
2 5 17 -150 200
;
run;


proc transpose data=a out=b(rename=(_NAME_=Date COL1=Transpose));
    var "Jul-09"n--"Sep-09"n;
    by ID Var1-Var2;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data a;
input ID Var1 Var2 Jul_09 Aug_09;
CARDS;
1 10 15 200 300
2 5 17 -150 200
;

DATA b(drop=i jul_09 aug_09);
array dates_{*} jul_09 aug_09;
set a;
do i=1 to dim(dates_);
    this_value=dates_{i};
    this_date=input(compress(vname(dates_{i}),'_'),MONYY5.);
    output;
end;
format this_date monyy5.;
run;
```